# Python design issues due to implementation of built-in max function

Tags: python

I use Python to wrap a powerful library (from another language) which manipulates expressions and relations. For that matter, I extensively use overloading of operators and it works like a charm.

Now, I would need to define a `max` function that would apply on my expressions to generate a new expression intuitively representing the "max of all expressions in the iterable (these expressions being not yet evaluated)."

Since the built-in function `max` uses iterators and some kind of order relation implemented as `__leq__`, etc., (which I use for generating relations from two expressions) I end up getting nonsense when I apply the built-in `max` on a set of expression.

More specifically,

```
>>> max(e1, e2, e3)
e3
```

although I would love to raise some kind of exception saying *"Please use my specific function I am pointing here that would generate the new expression you reasonably expect"*

My bottom-line is that even if I have a different function implementing `max` for expressions:

- I don't want to leave this behaviour as is and let users think they are safe doing `max(e1, e2, e3)`.
- I want `max` to work as usual with regular Python objects.

The only way-out of this issue I can think of would start by tricking the `key` option of `max` to raise an exception when it hits an object of a specific type:

```
def newkey(p):
    if isinstance(p, Expression):
        raise SyntaxError("Use function `foo` for computing `max`")
    # fallback to regular behaviour I know nothing about yet

max(e1, e2, e3, key=newkey)
```

Now I cannot force users to specify the `key` option each time they call `max`. As a matter of fact, if I could, I would tell them to use a different `max` function anyway...

Can you see a way out of this? (or a better workaround)

Comment: Why do you get nonsense? Why not implement `__leq__` correctly?

Comment: Because `__leq__ ` returns an instance of `Relation` which is not yet evaluated (as expressions are not yet evaluated) and is neither `True` nor `False`.

Comment: Define `__bool__` on `Relation` so it will be evaluated. Or `__nonzero__` if using Python 2.

Comment: I think if I were a user of your library, I would expect `max(e1, e2, e3)` to implicitly evaluate the expressions. You could design for this behavior, then add a `lazy_max` function to your module to return a `LazyMax` object. That covers all of your bases.

Comment: Well I am sure you wouldn't because it wouldn't make sense. :) It's not just about lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since the built-in function max uses iterators and some kind of order relation implemented as `__leq__`, etc., (which I use for generating relations from two expressions)

The type returned by your rich comparison methods needs to implement `__nonzero__`, or `__bool__` in Python 3, to define what happens when you try to interpret it as a boolean. There are two reasonable possibilities for what `__nonzero__` should do.

If it's reasonable to actually evaluate the underlying expressions and perform the comparison, you could design your `__nonzero__` method to just do that. This would make sense if you're building some sort of lazy operation library. In that case, `max` would just work, but it'd implicitly force evaluation of its arguments. That might not be desirable.

Alternatively, you could have `__nonzero__` raise a TypeError. In that case, when `max` tries to decide which of two Expressions is bigger, it'll raise a TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a decorator to override max it will provide the same behavior but raise exception when needed check the following code

```
def dec(ff):
    def _f(*args):
        for p in args:
            if isinstance(p, Expression):
                raise SyntaxError("Use function `foo` for computing `max`")
        else:
            return ff(*args)
    return _f

max = dec(max)
```